# How does routers and viewsets configure their urls?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I was reading through a long piece of code. And was stuck at how routers and viewsets automatically configure their URLs.
For eg.
the views.py file is:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,SessionAuthentication)
     permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
     serializer_class = UserSerializer
     queryset = User.objects.all()
```

The corresponding urls with router is:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users',views.UserViewSet,basename='user')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

In the above case, what will be the respective urls for the different actions in viewsets, ie list, create, retrieve, update, partial_update and destroy as mentioned in the djangorestframework documentation on viewsets: http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/viewsets

Answer (score 6):

When you register the viewset it will generate the following url patterns for above case.

```
router.register(prefix='users', viewset=views.UserViewSet, basename='user')
```

It follows the below regex patterns

```
# Regex for list
r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$'
# Regex for detail
r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$'
```

1.  List router allows `http` methods like `get` to retrieve the resource and `post` to create the resource.
2.  Detail router allows `http` methods like `get` to retrieve the data of a a resource,`put` to update the data of a resource, `patch` to partial update of resource and `delete` to delete the resource.

We can also pass a extra keyword argument `format` while using `reverse` to generate the dynamic url.

### URL patterns for above case

```
[<URLPattern '^users/$' [name='user-list']>,
 <URLPattern '^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='user-list']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$' [name='user-detail']>,
 <URLPattern '^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='user-detail']>,
 <URLPattern '^$' [name='api-root']>,
 <URLPattern '^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$' [name='api-root']>]
```

Reference: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py